# Event binding not working when I use the click property

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, data-binding, event-binding

I am trying to test event binding but it is not working when i use the click event, i'll attach code

This is my html template which works for the property binding

```
<!-- <h1 [innerHTML]="title"></h1>  -->
<!-- Above is another way but its normally easier if you just want to write out a value to use interpolation, like the one below -->

<h1 [hidden]="isVisible">{{title}}</h1> 
<button type="button" (click)="changeVisibility()">show/hide</button>
<!-- '!' basically means check the opposite, [hidden] is a property to hide an element using property binding in the DOM -->

<app-customers-list></app-customers-list>
<br>
```

This is mycomponent, the isVisible property binding works just fine but trying the event binding does not work, I even tried adding a console statement for each time I click but I received no log in my console

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core'; // first import the component decorator from angular
import { ICustomer } from '../shared/interfaces';
import { kMaxLength } from 'buffer';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-customers',
  standalone: false,
  templateUrl: './customers.component.html',
  styleUrl: './customers.component.css'
})
export class CustomersComponent implements OnInit {
  title: string = "";
  people: ICustomer[] = [];
  isVisible: boolean = false;

  changeVisibility() {
    this.isVisible = !this.isVisible;
    console.log("clicked", "false");
  }
  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.title = 'Customers';
    this.people = [
      { id: 1, name: 'john Doe', city: 'Phoenix', orderTotal: 9.99, customerSince: new Date(2014, 7, 10) },
      { id: 2, name: 'Jane Doe', city: 'Chandler', orderTotal: 19.99, customerSince: new Date(2017, 2, 22) },
      { id: 3, name: 'Michelle Thomas', city: 'Seattle', orderTotal: 99.99, customerSince: new Date(2002, 10, 31) },
      { id: 4, name: 'Jim Thomas', city: 'New York', orderTotal: 599.99, customerSince: new Date(2002, 10, 31) },
    ];
  }
}
```

I tried to click the button so that it would toggle the visibility as you can see in my code, the property binding works if i change it between true and false but the click event does not work, I received no error and I'm stumped (please ignore my comments, im still practicing :) )

Comment: Ideally your code should work. Is there any other errors in the console? Is `app-customers-list` causing any issues that is halting the execution of the app?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can't replicate the issue, here is a stackblitz where its working, do compare your code with this, please update the question with the reproducible issue!

ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { bootstrapApplication } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import 'zone.js';
import { CustomersListComponent } from './customers-list/customers-list.component';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [CustomersListComponent],
  template: `
    <!-- <h1 [innerHTML]="title"></h1>  -->
    <!-- Above is another way but its normally easier if you just want to write out a value to use interpolation, like the one below -->

    <h1 [hidden]="isVisible">{{title}}</h1> 
    <button type="button" (click)="changeVisibility()">show/hide</button>
    <!-- '!' basically means check the opposite, [hidden] is a property to hide an element using property binding in the DOM -->

    <app-customers-list></app-customers-list>
    <br>
  `,
})
export class App {
  title: string = '';
  people: any[] = [];
  isVisible: boolean = false;

  changeVisibility() {
    this.isVisible = !this.isVisible;
    console.log('clicked', 'false');
  }
  constructor() {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.title = 'Customers';
    this.people = [
      {
        id: 1,
        name: 'john Doe',
        city: 'Phoenix',
        orderTotal: 9.99,
        customerSince: new Date(2014, 7, 10),
      },
      {
        id: 2,
        name: 'Jane Doe',
        city: 'Chandler',
        orderTotal: 19.99,
        customerSince: new Date(2017, 2, 22),
      },
      {
        id: 3,
        name: 'Michelle Thomas',
        city: 'Seattle',
        orderTotal: 99.99,
        customerSince: new Date(2002, 10, 31),
      },
      {
        id: 4,
        name: 'Jim Thomas',
        city: 'New York',
        orderTotal: 599.99,
        customerSince: new Date(2002, 10, 31),
      },
    ];
  }
}

bootstrapApplication(App);
```

[<kbd>**`Stackblitz Demo`**</kbd>](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-wjmzpb?description=An%20angular-cli%20project%20based%20on%20@angular/animations,%20@angular/common,%20@angular/compiler,%20@angular/core,%20@angular/forms,%20@angular/platform-browser,%20@angular/platform-browser-dynamic,%20@angular/router,%20core-js,%20rxjs,%20tslib%20and%20zone.js&file=src%2Fmain.ts,src%2Fcustomers-list%2Fcustomers-list.component.ts&title=Angular%20Starter)

Comment: I checked your code and it works, I used it to compare with my code but mine still does not toggle, only the property binding part works, I'm so confused

Comment: @MadukaSamuel Is it possible to replicate the issue on the stackblitz?

Comment: @MadukaSamuel please check the `console` for any errors!

Comment: I tried it on the stackblitz but theres no issue there, I used the exact same code, in the same format but it does not work on mine, no error in console and it does not log anything when clicked. It logs on the stackblitz but when i try the code on my vs code it does not work, only the property binding still works i.e changing i manually from true to false

Comment: @MadukaSamuel Create a new component then try checking the click event on that component! just the click event, no other extra code!

Comment: I tried it on a new component and it still didnt work, but the property binding part still works

Comment: @MadukaSamuel if possible share the github repo! to reproduce the issue!

Comment: It worked!! I had to change the configuration of my main.ts file though, it was initially :
```
import { bootstrapApplication } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { appConfig } from './app/app.config';
import { AppModule } from './app/app.module';

bootstrapApplication(AppModule, appConfig)
  .catch((err) => console.error(err));
```

But i changed it to :
```
import {platformBrowserDynamic} from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
import { AppModule } from './app/app.module';
 platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule)
 .catch((err) => console.error(err));
```

Comment: I've edited my previous answer to show how I fixed it, thank you so much for your assistance your answer gave me much needed clarity